# In ChessBase, how can I force the deep analysis function to analyze a specific variation?

Tags: chessbase

For example, say I want to run deep analysis on 1.d4, but I'd like to ensure 1.d4 h3 is looked at, how can I achieve this?

From the chessbase manual:
"Variations that are in the notation at the start of the analysis are never deleted and are always analysed, unless they are the results of a previous Cloud Analysis."

I've tried starting the analysis with 1.d4 h3 in the notation, but as soon as I hit deep analysis, h3 is removed from the notation and not looked at (and no, it's not a result of a previous cloud analysis).

Does anyone know how to achieve the behavior I'm after?

I'm on ChessBase 17 with the latest update.

Comment: We aren't the ChessBase help center.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Why is there a chessbase tag if I can't post chessbase questions

Comment: Not everything about ChessBase is applicable as a question.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Would you mind improving the tag info then to elaborate on what it should be used for so that I don't make the same mistake again and can better understand what types of chessbase questions I can post?

Comment: Looking at the tag again, it seems whether or not closing questions asking how to use portions of ChessBase is inconsistently applied. Yet, then there are plenty of open questions of how to use lichess and chess.com... seems to be time for a meta question to revisit the subject as a whole perhaps.

Comment: I'll just throw in that I came to this forum for help specifically because chessbase doesn't have it's own dedicated forums like chess.com or lichess.org. This stack exchange currently exists as the best option to build a knowledge base of information on chessbase, whether its usage-specific or not.

Answer (score 2):

> say I want to run deep analysis on 1.d4, but I'd like to ensure 1.d4 h3 is looked at, how can I achieve this?

In previous versions of Chessbase (I still use Chessbase 6) the way to achieve this kind of thing was to construct your own opening book containing only the opening lines you wanted it to look at and tell Chessbase to use this book.